# Can't connect to DB in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, oracle-sqldeveloper, portforwarding, oracle-xe

I'm having a problem when trying to connect to a DB installed in my Redhat virtual machine.

I have oracle XE installed in my VM. Here is my port forwarding configuration:

[image: Port Forwarding]

However, when I try to connect using the SQL developer on Windows, I can't get a connection and I get the following error when testing the connection:

[image: sqlDev]

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you connect to the VMs IP/port directly instead of via port forwarding?

Comment: Won't work, it has to be port forwarding

Comment: Is there a firewall running on the guest? Is the listener on the right guest IP? Can you connect internally - running the Linux version of SQL Developer for example? (As a test, not suggesting you should have to always do that.)

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I had to stop iptables in my VM

Comment: Good - guess you could turn that into an answer, or show how to modify the firewall to allow 1521; but this is more of a Super User/Server Fault issue, not really specific to Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

All I had to do was stop the iptables firewall in RHEL

```
service iptables stop
```

I've removed iptables so this won't happen again, but that is entirely up to you!